# Integrate a smooth function when integrate() fails

Tags: r, math, numerical-methods, integral

When trying to integrate the following smooth function with `integrate()` in R, I always obtain an error, either the "integral is probably divergent" or "maximum number of subdivisions reached":

[image]

The problem seems to be that the function approaches zero at around +/-1, but it is difficult to set the limits appropriately, and increasing `subdivisions` or reducing `rel.tol` does not help.

Are there other integration routines in R (or in R packages) that I could try? Is there e.g. a routine for simple Simpson integration available for equidistantly sampled functions?

**Edit:** As someone asked, here is the implementation of the function:

```
a <- -1
b <- 1
sigma <- 0.1

# P(Y >= t)
PY <- function(t) {
  za <- (t-a)/sigma
  zb <- (t-b)/sigma
  1 + sigma/(b-a) * (zb*pnorm(zb) + dnorm(zb) - za*pnorm(za) - dnorm(za))
}

# P(Y >= t | X=x)
PY.x <- function(t, x) {
  1 - pnorm((t-x)/sigma)
}

# density of Y: p(y)
p.y <- function(y) {
  zb <- (b-y)/sigma
  za <- (a-y)/sigma
  1/(b-a) * (pnorm(zb) - pnorm(za))
}

# Var in numerator
Var.Yt <- function(t) {
  integrand <- function(x) {
    (PY.x(t,x) - PY(t))^2
  }
  integrate(integrand, a, b)$value
}

# THIS IS THE FUNCTION TO BE INTEGRATED
f <- function(t) {
  Var.Yt(t)*p.y(t)
}
```

The computation of `Var.Yt(t)` succeeds for any value of `t`, but the integration of `f` fails with the aforementioned error.

Comment: show your smooth function

Comment: It is a bit intricate, because the function itself is defined by calling `integrate`, I have checked, though, that this inner integration always works for arbitrary parameters. I will add it to my qusation.

Comment: You can try `pracma::integral()`

Comment: (1) Depends on what goal you're working towards, but anyway given the definition in terms of a Gaussian density and its integral (which is proportional to erf), it might be possible to work out an symbolic expression for the integral in question in terms of sigma. (2) It looks like you might be computing a conditional variance for a Gaussian distribution. If so, I think that has a known result. See e.g. Richard von Mises, "Mathematical Theory of Probability and Statistics," Chapter VIII if I remember correctly. No doubt such results are presented elsewhere as well.

Comment: @robert-dodier Yes, I think the integral can be evaluated in symbolic form because the integrad is a polynomial in x, phi(x), and Phi(x), with the highest order term x^2 phi(x)^2 Phi(x)^2, so that it should be computable by partial integration and the formulas from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions. At present I did not have the time to carry this out, so I resorted to the "fast track" of numerical integration at the price of losing some precision. Bonus of the numerical integration is that I can adapt the code for more complicated use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to ***vectorize*** your function `f` before pushing it to `integrate` or `pramca::integral`.

Here you can see they would work if we apply `Vectorize()`

```
> pracma::integral(Vectorize(f), -2, 2)
[1] 0.2799594

> integrate(Vectorize(f), -2, 2)
0.2799594 with absolute error < 5.4e-06
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it! Now I can even use the limits `-Inf` and `Inf`. Thanks!